# DELL Inspiron 5555

Tags: memory, dell-inspiron

I currently have 4G memory on a DELL inspiron 5555. 
In the internet, it says I can add 8+8 on a dell inspire 5555 (15-5555).

In the System Information, we find:

- Total Virtual Memory: 8.22G
- Available Virtual memory: 6.17 G Page
- File space ? :  4.88G

Should I buy 1 more 4G?
Or one 8G?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the age of the machine and the use you put it to. Most of my clients (normal business works) are happy with machines that have 8 GB of memory. If the machine is 3 or 4 years old, I would limit the expense and at 4 GB.  If newer and you use many simultaneous applications, plus 8 GB may be a good idea.

Comment: It is older than 4 years, I guess. I use it mostly with a hotspot for normal business use, but always with a few tabs on the browser and/or a couple of applications.

Comment: Is 4+4 different from one 8? (Reason is that I could buy one 8 now and another 8 in the future.

Comment: Yes, I think you are on the right track. I use 16 GB in my own machines here.